# Understanding the AWS Streaming

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to use the AWS Video Stream and I am lost in what types there are.

What I found was Amazon Kinesis which has :

- Amazon Kinesis Data Streams .
- Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose .
- Amazon Managed Streaming for Apache Kafka (Amazon MSK) .

MY Question is are these in the above are used to stream a video in each one of them or do they work together to do it ? if not , Is there any other types other than the kinesis where it belong to the AWS ?

Comment: Rather than concentrating on product names, can you describe what goal you are wanting to achieve? For example, what do you want to do with a video stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seems like you are a bit confused.

**Amazon Kinesis Data Streams** - is useful for rapidly moving data off data producers and then continuously processing the data, whether that means transforming it before emitting to a data store, running real-time metrics and analytics, or deriving more complex data streams for further processing.

some of Kinesis Data Stream use cases are: real-time metrics and reporting, real-time data analytics, log and event data collection and power event-driven applications.

**Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose** - is a streaming ETL solution. It is the easiest way to load streaming data into data stores and analytics tools. It can capture, transform, and load streaming data into Amazon S3, Amazon Redshift, Amazon OpenSearch Service, and Splunk, enabling near real-time analytics with existing business intelligence tools and dashboards you’re already using today. It is a fully managed service that automatically scales to match the throughput of your data and requires no ongoing administration. It can also batch, compress, and encrypt the data before loading it, minimizing the amount of storage used at the destination and increasing security.

**Amazon MSK** - is a managed Kafka cluster.

For streaming video AWS provide **Kinesis Video Streams**

which makes it easy to securely stream media from connected devices to AWS for storage, analytics, machine learning (ML), playback, and other processing. Kinesis Video Streams automatically provisions and elastically scales all the infrastructure needed to ingest streaming media from millions of devices. It durably stores, encrypts, and indexes media in your streams, and allows you to access your media through easy-to-use APIs. Kinesis Video Streams enables you to quickly build computer vision and ML applications through integration with Amazon Rekognition Video, Amazon SageMaker, and libraries for ML frameworks such as Apache MxNet, TensorFlow, and OpenCV. For live and on-demand playback, Kinesis Video Streams provides fully-managed capabilities for HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) and Dynamic Adaptive Streaming over HTTP (DASH). Kinesis Video Streams also supports ultra-low latency two-way media streaming with WebRTC, as a fully managed capability.

Depends on your use case, you might also find **Elemental MediaLive** useful.
It is a cloud-based live video encoding service that offers fast, reliable and easy-to-use delivery of high-quality live video streams without the need to manage infrastructure

Comment: does kinesis video streams prevent watchers from downloading the stream? Just like netflix and hulu?